# Nodejitsu on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, npm, nodejitsu

I've just started playing around with Node.js and was trying to get Nodejitsu to work on my system (Windows 7, Node version 0.8.15)

I installed Jitsu using the "npm install jitsu -g" command, but beyond that trying to perform jitsu users confirm or deploy returns:

> 'jitsu' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I understand that I most probably need to add the jitsu install location in my path, but am not sure where jitsu has been installed.

Help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on a normal Node.js installation on windows you will find the npm modules located at

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
```

or in

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\jitsu
```

You need to set up the PATH environment variable to the correct path

An then you will be able to use Nodejitsu :)